# Hibernate query to get child

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, criteria

i want to fetch all child users.
and i have two columns parent and child

in parent table--

```
id  pname  pid(fk of parent)

1   A
2   B      1
3   C      2
```

in child table---

```
id  cname  cid(fk of child)  pid(fk of parent)

1    AA                       1
2    BA     1                 2
3    BC     2                 2
4    CA     3                 3
5    CC     4                 3
```

if parent A --
get all child

if parent B--
get BA,BB,CA,CC

if parent C--
get CA,CC

i vl get the answer but its not single query.. thers any hibernate single query to do this

update..............

```
public class Parent implements PersistEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="OH",sequenceName="OH", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="OH")
    private Long parentid;

    @Column(name = "parent_name")
    private String parentName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_parent_id")
    private Parent  fkparentId;
}

public class Child implements PersistEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="OP",sequenceName="OP",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="OP")
    private Long childId;

    @Column(name = "child_name")
    private String childName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_child_id")
    private Child fkchildId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_office_hierarchy_parent")
    private Parent fkparentId;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. But this still looks like a question that basically asks for code written to your spec. We're not a free code writing service.

Comment: When using Hibernate, you are coding and writing queries against the class model, not the tables. That's one reason for having an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved using Recursive query in jpa